# Filter data by a specific id for display in ReactJS

Tags: json, api, reactjs

I want to select the data that matches this specific id. I have made an API call which gives me this JSON data, but I only want the data where the id is `eb9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347`. How do I filter just this data?

```
     [
          {
            "food_item_id": "a095eca7-3dcf-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
            "food_group_id": "eb9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
            "food_item_name": "Don't know jack"
          },
          {
            "food_item_id": "a09b073d-3dcf-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
            "food_group_id": "ebaeef2c-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
            "food_item_name": "Oreo cookie monster"
          },
          {
        "food_item_id": "a180332e-3dcf-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
        "food_group_id": "ab9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-69e8124",
        "food_item_name": "Big Country"                  
      }
        ]
```

How do I filter by `"food_group_id": "eb9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347"`:

```
var canvases = this.state.foodinfo.map(function(data) {
         return (
           <div>
           <Card className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 eachCard">
             <CardImg top width="100%" src={data.food_item_pic} alt="Card image cap" />
             <CardBlock className="cardBlock">
               <CardTitle>{data.food_item_name}</CardTitle>
               <CardSubtitle>${data.food_item_price}</CardSubtitle>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign btnClass"></span>
             </CardBlock>
           </Card>
           </div>
         );
       });
```

I added a filter before `map`, but I am getting an error on the item of the array:

```
var canvases = this.state.foodinfo.filter(item => food_group_id=== 'eb9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347').map(function(data) {
             return (
               <div>
               <Card className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 eachCard">
                 <CardImg top width="100%" src={data.food_item_pic} alt="Card image cap" />
                 <CardBlock className="cardBlock">
                   <CardTitle>{data.food_item_name}</CardTitle>
                   <CardSubtitle>${data.food_item_price}</CardSubtitle>
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign btnClass"></span>
                 </CardBlock>
               </Card>
               </div>
             );
           });
```

Comment: `.filter( item => item.food_group_id=== '...' ).map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should't it be `filter(item => item.food_group_id ===`?